# Change the color of the selection in CSS

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a page with such a component: (the screenshot shows the view and the code of this component):

[image]

I don't know what this component is. I need to change the color of selected items to red (select option with parametr "selected"). Item without "selected" it may still be gray.

```
<select name="user_ids[]" id="user_ids" class="form-control edited" style="background-image: none !important;" required="" multiple="">
                <option value="1" data-role="root" selected="">Admin</option>
                <option value="2" data-role="root">User</option>
                <option value="6" data-role="admin" selected="">Andrzej</option>
            </select>
```

How can I make it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use :

```css
select[multiple]:focus option:checked {
    background: red linear-gradient(0deg, red 0%, red 100%);
}
```

```html
<select name="user_ids[]" id="user_ids" class="form-control edited" style="background-image: none !important;" required="" multiple="">
    <option value="1" data-role="root" selected="">Admin</option>
    <option value="2" data-role="root">User</option>
    <option value="6" data-role="admin" selected="">Andrzej</option>
</select>
```

or

```css
option[selected] {
    background: red;
}
```

```html
<select name="user_ids[]" id="user_ids" class="form-control edited" style="background-image: none !important;" required="" multiple="">
    <option value="1" data-role="root" selected="">Admin</option>
    <option value="2" data-role="root">User</option>
    <option value="6" data-role="admin" selected="">Andrzej</option>
</select>
```